# Trasform two ULs in one

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-mobile

Hi to all css gurus :D

I've this situation (on mobile):

```
<ul>
 <li>one</li>
 <li>two</li>
</ul>
<ul>
 <li>three</li>
 <li>four</li>
</ul>
```

and I want, when in landascape mode via @media, change it to this (without display: none etc):

```
<ul>
 <li>one</li>
 <li>two</li>
 <li>three</li>
 <li>four</li>
</ul>
```

Is there any method to hide just a portion of a tag? like `</ul>` but `<ul>` ?
I prefer a css solution but also JS or JQ is ok of course ;)

thanks

Comment: Can you post some more example code and some CSS?

Comment: but I want to "convert" two sequential ul in one, it's like delete the `</ul><ul>`

Comment: yep, infant now I've two blocks, one with two ul and one with one, and via `display:none` I change the situation.... but this is not a great solution :(

Comment: Is it simply for presentation-purposes you want to merge the `<ul>`s into one?

Comment: Could you use something like this instead? http://www.quirksmode.org/css/multicolumn.html

Answer (score 3):

If you have jQuery installed you can do it like this:

```
var u = $('ul').first(); //select your first ul element, you can do it by id or class selector
u.append(u.next().html());
u.next().remove();
```

Answer (score 1):

You can easily do it with JQUERY, see: http://jsfiddle.net/w9dFS/

**** Added jQuery Mobile orientation function, to check if its landscape.

```
if(jQuery.event.special.orientationchange.orientation() = "landscape") {
    //Search all UL's with a higher index than 0
    $('ul:gt(0)').each( function() {
        //Get the content of the UL's
        var content = $(this).html();
        //Hide the UL
        $(this).hide();
        //Insert the content into the first UL
        $('ul:eq(0)').append(content);
    });
}
```

Else you could add a CSS class to the other UL's and use simple CSS to "reset" the style.

A simple CSS fix could be:

```
/* Landscape */
@media screen and (orientation:landscape) {
   /* Landscape styles here */
    ul {margin-top:0px;}
    ul:first-child {margin-top:50px;}
}
```

I dont know what CSS you need to remove on the others, but normally margin is the only thing differenting style.

Comment: But how can I trigger that in landscape mode? I'm with jq mobile

Comment: Thanks, maybe I'm in the wrong way but this is currently my situation: [http://jsfiddle.net/w9dFS/46/](http://jsfiddle.net/w9dFS/46/) I've tried also to change in JQ the ul with the JQ mobile's automatic appended class but nothing seems to work

Comment: Im playing around with it, but im having problems with the block element... See http://jsfiddle.net/w9dFS/48/

Comment: Yep, it's not so easy override jqmob, I've also tried with css with no luck

Answer (score 0):

Here is a dummy CSS only solution:

```
<div class="showmode1">
<ul>
 <li>one</li>
 <li>two</li>
</ul>
<ul>
 <li>three</li>
 <li>four</li>
</ul>
</div>

<div class="showmode2">
<ul>
 <li>one</li>
 <li>two</li>
 <li>three</li>
 <li>four</li>
</ul>
</div>
```

Then set up your css rules so that in landscape
showmode2 is displayed and showmode1 is none

And, it other situation
showmode2 is none and showmode1 is displayed

I know this is extra div, but it does have the advantage of being css only. If the lists are small content. Maybe the slight bloat will not be a problem.

Nice thing about this is that you also have option to change the words a little and/or change the sequence of the li etc.

Comment: this is my current situation but it's not a solution cause I've to write two time the code

Comment: anyway my css with your solution is:
`@media screen and (orientation:landscape){
 . showmode1{display: none !important}
 . showmode2{display: block !important}

}`

Answer (score 0):

The vanilla approach (jQuery is not the answer to everything, despite of [this](http://www.doxdesk.com/img/updates/20091116-so-large.gif)):

#### Apply selectors

```html
<ul id="first-list">
    <li>one</li>
    <li>two</li>
</ul>
<ul id="second-list">
    <li>three</li>
    <li>four</li>
</ul>
```

#### Append the inner HTML

```js
var firstList = document.getElementById('first-list');
var secondList = document.getElementById('second-list');
secondList.innerHTML = firstList.innerHTML + secondList.innerHTML;
```

[<sub>[image: jsfiddle-icon]</sub> **Demo**](https://i.stack.imgur.com/w0ll3.png)

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to collapse any CSS styles using media queries for landscape view so you shouldn't need to mess with JavaScript to solve this.

```
ul { margin:0 0 1em; padding:1em; }
li { margin:0 1em .5em; padding:0; }
/* Landscape */
@media screen and (min-width: 321px) {
  ul + ul { padding-top:0; margin-top:-2em; }
}
```

You can view the demo either on your mobile or resize the browser window so it's narrower than usual, about `350px` wide.

**Demo: [turi.co/up/merge_ul.html](http://marcel.turi.co/up/merge_ul.html)**

Obviously, without seeing any more of your CSS or other markup, this is a good answer, but it may not be suitable to your situation.

Comment: this is my situation, with JQ mobile it's not so easy ;)  http://jsfiddle.net/w9dFS/56/